# Any Idea why this script is giving red X's in the email for the images

Tags: powershell

```
Send-MailMessage -From "Snoopy <Snoopy@Brand.com>" -To"Jermaine <jmaine@Brand.com>" -Subject "Weekly Headcount Report" -Attachments "\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image001.png", "\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image002.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image003.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image004.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image005.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image006.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image007.png","\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image008.png" -SmtpServer "smtp.Brand.com" -Body '<html> <body> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image001.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image002"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image003.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image004.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image005.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image006.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image007.png"><br> <img src="cid:2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image008.png"><br> </body> </html>' -BodyAsHtml
```

I have tried all kinds of different things to get this to work, but so far I get red X's no matter what.  I tried differing modifications of this script  I found on SO and other places.  One of them had InlineAttachments in there and powershell threw an error on that parameter. The attachments are there and not corrupted, but they aren't showing up in the body.

I have powershell 5.0.10586.117

Since everyone wants to point at my post and say it is exact copy of another I will address that:

problem is I already copied the EXACT code at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d and it didn't work. I am not getting any errors, but I am also not getting any emails.

```
$images = @{ 
    image1 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image001.png' 
    image2 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image002.png'
    image3 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image003.png'
    image4 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image004.png'
    image5 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image005.png'
    image6 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image006.png'
    image7 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image007.png'
    image8 = '\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\2017 snerk Headcount_25311_image008.png'
}  

$body = @' 
<html>  
  <body>  
    <img src="cid:image1"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image2"><br>
    <img src="cid:image3"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image4"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image5"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image6"><br>  
    <img src="cid:image7"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image8"><br> 
  </body>  
</html>  
'@  

$params = @{ 
    InlineAttachments = $images 
    Body = $body 
    BodyAsHtml = $true 
    Subject = "Test email" 
    From = 'Snoopy@Brand.com' 
    To = 'jmaine@Brand.com' 
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.Brand.com' 
} 

.\Send-MailMessage.ps1 @params
```

I have also tried:

```
$files = get-childitem "\\portal2010.Brand.com\sites\snerk HC\snerk HC Dashboards\2017 JE Headcount_files\" | where name -like "*.png"
$body = @()
$attachments = @()
foreach($file in $files){
    $filename = [system.io.path]::GetFileName($file.FullName)
    $attachments += $file.fullname
    $body += "<br /><img src='" + $filename + "'/><br />"
}
$body = $body | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -to "Jermaine <jmaine@Brand.com>" -From "Snoopy <Snoopy@Brand.com>" -SmtpServer "smtp.Brand.com" -Subject "Test" -BodyAsHtml $body -Attachments $attachments
```

Red X's in the Body.

So yes this may be just like that question, except the answer there didn't fix my problem.

Comment: `Attachments` are not available for use within the email body, they are isolated files intended for delivery to the recipient.

Comment: One tip I can give you for keywords to search for to solve this problem : Powershell Send-Mailmessage Inline attachment.

Comment: While it may be a duplicate, the answer in the other post does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where I finally got to and have it working.

```
$SendTo = "email1@brand.com"
$CCTo1 = "email2@brand.com"
$CCTo2 = "email3@brand.com"
$CCTo3 = "email5@brand.com"
$CCTo4 = "email6@brand.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.brand.com" 
$EmailFrom = "email7@brand.com"
$EmailSubject = "Weekly HC Email"

$Image2 = '\\portal2010.brand.com\sites\HC\HC Dashboards\2017 JE HC_files\2017 HC_10419_image002.png'
$Image4 = '\\portal2010.brand.com\sites\HC\HC Dashboards\2017 JE HC_files\2017 HC_10419_image004.png'
$Image6 = '\\portal2010.brand.com\sites\HC\HC Dashboards\2017 JE HC_files\2017 HC_10419_image006.png'
$Image8 = '\\portal2010.brand.com\sites\HC\HC Dashboards\2017 JE HC_files\2017 HC_10419_image008.png'

$Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue

$att2 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image2)
$att2.ContentId = "att2"
$att4 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image4)
$att4.ContentId = "att4"
$att6 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image6)
$att6.ContentId = "att6"
$att8 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image8)
$att8.ContentId = "att8"

$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$body = '
        <img src="cid:att2" /><br/><br/>
        <img src="cid:att4" /><br/><br/>
        <img src="cid:att6" /><br/><br/>
        <img src="cid:att8" /><br/><br/>
'

$Message.From = $EmailFrom
$Message.To.Add($SendTo)
$Message.Cc.Add($CCTo1)
$Message.Cc.Add($CCTo2)
$Message.Cc.Add($CCTo3)
$Message.Cc.Add($CCTo4)
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.Body = $body
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Message.Attachments.Add($att2)
$Message.Attachments.Add($att4)
$Message.Attachments.Add($att6)
$Message.Attachments.Add($att8)
$smtp.Send($Message)
```